# UK family visit visa with borrowed money in the bank

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to apply for a UK family visa for a week. I live in France with a four-year resident card. I am a Bangladeshi citizen.

I see about funds parking everywhere, but I have a loan from bank to buy a car which I didn't buy yet because I failed to pass my driving test. If I apply for the visa now, would the ECO consider this money to be funds parking?

I have enough funds apart from this loan in my current bank account; with this money I can handle a one-week trip to the UK.

Comment: By ‘handle’ do you mean ‘I have more than sufficient for’? ie is what you plan to spend proportionate to your monthly income & savings (excluding the car loan funds, as you state)

Comment: I meant ive sufficient funds for a one week trip in england ..ive my monthl income n some savimg aswell

Comment: ‘Proportionality’ means that, for example, you’re not planning to spend day 4x your monthly income and/or your entire savings on the trip.

Comment: No im not going to spend all the money i meant ive enough funds for example ive 2000 euros and i wish to spend 600euros for the trip bcoz i wont have to pay the hotel n food coz i will stay at my uncles

Answer (score 2):

If you include the all the bank statements from the receipt of the loan until the most recent, and a copy of the loan documents, and you indicate that you will not be relying on those funds for your trip because you intend to use them to purchase a car, you should be fine.

The problem with "funds parking" arises when the funds are claimed as available to defray the costs of the trip, or when it is not obvious that they were acquired legitimately.

Further reading: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/19400)